# How do the liberal side of international relations theorists model people’s well-being?

Tags: international-relations, political-theory, liberalism

I’m only referring to the liberal side of [international relations theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_relations_theory), not the realist side.

In their formal theories (to the extent that they write mathematically formal  theories), how do they model people’s well-being? Do they tend to take a deontological view (more about rights and rules), or do they they a more utilitarian view like the economists?

Comment: Do they model people's well-being? If you take a deontological view, e.g. human-rights-based policy (which seems the dominant view on the liberal side), then you don't need to model anyone's well-being to know what's right or wrong.

Comment: @StuartF Thanks much for the answer. The problem with deontological views, of course, is that they are often internally inconsistent. The rights of one person often conflicts with the rights of another person. We can pretend that there are no conflicts/trade-offs while there are. Do IR theorists deal with this at all?